# Multiple vhosts on one and the same docker container

Tags: apache, docker, virtualhost

I'm trying to run two different domains on one and the same Docker container and port.

The Docker container runs CentOS. `docker-compose.yml` looks like so:

```
web:
  image: fab/centos
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src/httpd.conf:/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - ./src:/var/www/html
    - ./src/hosts:/etc/hosts
  environment:
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=dummy.dev,tests.dev
```

I also declared both .dev domain names inside of `/etc/hosts` on the host computer (OS X.)

It's been a while since I configured virtual hosts. My understanding was that I just needed to declare them and that Apache would automatically serve the proper files depending on the HTTP HOST being requested.

This is what I have, added at the end of `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # first host = default host
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/default
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dummy
    ServerName dummy.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy.dev
    ErrorLog logs/dummy.dev-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy.dev-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tests
    ServerName tests.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tests.dev
    ErrorLog logs/tests.dev-error_log
    CustomLog logs/tests.dev-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However, in practice, visiting either dummy.dev or tests.dev actually serves `/var/www/html/default`. This is as if Apache didn't realize which host is being called (though a dump of `$_SERVER` in PHP does show the expected `HTTP_HOST` value, i.e.: either 127.0.0.1, dummy.dev or tests.dev depending on which URL I visit.)

What did I miss?

It's unclear to me whether this is an Apache issue or a Docker one.

(Please note this is a different question from how to host multiple apps on the same domain with different port. In my case, I do want the virtual hosts to be all inside/on the same app/port/container.)

Comment: can you give me the code on `./src` folder on your repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was an Apache configuration issue.

I needed to explicitly enable domain-named virtualhosts, like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

[This answer helped.](https://serverfault.com/a/439911)

Docker had nothing to do with the matter.

Comment: NameVirtualHost has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The `fab/centos` does not exist in public docker hub, so not sure why you are experiencing the issue.

My recommendation would be to take a step back and try to make it work with a simple example.

`docker search apache` yields `eboraas/apache` as most starred image, so I'll use that one for the example.

In a test directory, use your sample:

File: httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> # first host = default host
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/default
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dummy
    ServerName dummy.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy.dev
    ErrorLog logs/dummy.dev-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy.dev-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tests
    ServerName tests.dev
    ServerAdmin webmaster@tests.dev
    ErrorLog logs/tests.dev-error_log
    CustomLog logs/tests.dev-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then create the vhost websites & the logs directory.

```
mkdir -p logs; for i in default tests dummy; do mkdir -p $i; echo "hello $i" > $i/index.html; done
```

Finally, run docker.

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/var/www/html -v $(pwd)/httpd.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf -v $(pwd)/logs:/etc/apache2/logs -p 9090:80 --rm --name apache_c eboraas/apache
```

Note that I use basically the same volumes as you did in your docker-compose.yml, except that I use `site-available` instead of changing the httpd.conf.

To test, make sure you have tests.dev and dummy.dev in your /etc/hosts pointing at the right Docker IP and test:

```
$> curl dummy.dev:9090
hello dummy
$> curl tests.dev:9090
hello tests
```

From this point, build up on top of this by first trying the docker apache image that you are using, then try with your custom /etc/hosts file, then put it back in a docker-compose file

Comment: I am trying to follow this example and it seems to be working *except* that visiting either `dummy.dev:9090` or `tests.dev:9090` in any browser attempts to redirect to https and then gives me the following warning: `SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.`

Answer (score 1):

Turn on NameVirtualHost in your httpd config:

File : /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
NameVirtualHost *:443
```