# Docker Virtualhost outside container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have `Docker` running right, but I want to change the name of server name, right now it's work with this way `http://localhost:8080`, but I want to use another url for the same host, it's possible?

I already have configured inside the container the virtualhost, and add `127.0.0.1` test.local in `/etc/hosts` everything inside my container. 
 Now, from inside my container, the URL(test.local)  response well, but when I try from outside only work whit `localhost:8080`.

Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a docker container that is listening by a name instead of using a localhost with different port.

1. Add the dns entry for the Server Name you need in the /etc/hosts

   $ nano /etc/hosts

   127.0.0.1      test.local
2. Edit the composer.yml

version: '2'

```
 services: 
 web:
    build: ./docker/
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/app
    tty: true
    extra_hosts:
        - "test.local:127.0.0.1"
    hostname: test
    domainname: local
```

3. Add the Server Name in the DockerFile:

   RUN printf "127.0.0.1    api.local" >> /etc/hosts
4. Configure the virtual host in the DockerFile
5. Build the container:

   $ docker-compose up -d
6. Check the hostname have been applied to the container:

$ docker exec -it test_local_web_1 hostname

And it should return:

$ test.local

7. Check server is running and listening by the server name:

$ curl -get http://test.local

Answer (score 0):

The main question to ask is your case is:

**Local Docker development with virtual hosts**

Please read about `--network=host` or in Docker-Compose `network_mode: "host"`.

Please check:

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/ and

[Multiple vhosts on one and the same docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786208/multiple-vhosts-on-one-and-the-same-docker-container)